# Append array into the array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have an array of objects as shown below.

```
var myArray = [
{
Data:  '455',
Note: 'tre',
Id: '4'
}, 
{
Data: '456',
Note: 'bre',
Id: '5'
}, 
{
Data: '457',
Note: 'cre',
Id: '6'
}
];
```

I also have this array

```
Percent = [ '10', '20', '30'],
```

Can someone please let me know how do i add this array elements into the array of objects. tHe expected output is as follows.

```
var myArray = [
{
Data:  '455',
Note: 'tre',
Id: '4',
Percent: '10'
}, 
{
Data: '456',
Note: 'bre',
Id: '5',
Percent: '20'
}, 
{
Data: '457',
Note: 'cre',
Id: '6',
Percent: '30'
}
];
```

Comment: With Lodash: `_.zipWith(myArray, Percent, function(o, p) { o.Percent = p; });`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Percent` always contains the same number of items as `myArray`, loop over `myArray` and assign the correct value from `Percent` like this:

```
myArray.forEach(function(object,index) {
  object.Percent = Percent[index];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same assumption as @Adam, but using ES6 arrow function feature:

```
myArray.map((x,i) => x.Percent = percent[i]);
```

here is a plunker : [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/h3nywuxR5GEXUNTNzKfw?p=preview)

Don't forget to check browser compatibility : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)